# Terminology for a "subgroup" that has a different identity element.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology, semigroups, monoid

Let $M$ denote a monoid. Then to refer to submonoids of $M$ that just happens to be a group, I think the phrase "subgroup of $M$" is okay, as it's unlikely to cause confusion as long as you instruct the reader you'll be using the word in this way.

However, sometimes you've got a monoid $M$ with a subsemigroup $M$ that just happens to be a group, but whose identity element is different to that of $M$. This happens with [sandpiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_sandpile_model) for example; there's a monoid $M$ of sandpiles, and this has a special "subgroup", but the subgroup has a different identity element to $M$.

> **Question.** Is there a term for this?

Comment: Is'nt the unit element of a monoid uniquely determined? If $e,e'$ are two identity elements, then $e = e\cdot e' = e'$.

Comment: Yes. The identity element in the subgroup isn't an identity in the larger monoid. It's just an idempotent.

Comment: Note also that the inverses in those subgroups will not be inverses in the original monoid (because the product is the group identity, not the monoid identity).

Comment: Indeed, an element in such a “wrong-identity subgroup” *cannot* be monoid-invertible; If $e$ is the monoid identity and $i$ is the subgroup identity and $a$ is both in the subgroup (thus in particular $ia=a$) and monoid-invertible with inverse $a^{-1}$ (that is, $aa^{-1}=e$), then we have $e = aa^{-1} = iaa^{-1} = ie = i$.

Comment: I am not sure if there is any specific name for this, as it will tend to be the case for "most" subgroups (each idempotent will be contained in a maximal subgroup).

Comment: @celtschk, nice argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In semigroup theory, the accepted terminology is the following. 
A *subgroup* of a semigroup $S$ is a subsemigroup of $S$ that happens to be a group. In particular, its identity is an idempotent, although $S$ might have no identity.

In $S$ is a monoid with identity $1$, a subgroup whose identity is $1$ is a subgroup of the *group of units* of $S$. You may also simply call it a *subgroup with identity $1$*.

That being said, I agree that this leads to some confusion. For instance, how do you define a submonoid of a monoid? The official definition insists on having the same identity. Thus you arrive to the conclusion that a subgroup of a monoid $M$ is not necessarily a submonoid of $M$. Furthermore, if $S$ is a semigroup and $e$ is an idempotent, the subsemigroup $eSe$ happens to be a monoid with identity $e$, sometimes called the *local submonoid of $S$ at $e$*.